# Taking a list and printing all of the indexes of the elements that aren't equal to 0

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have to take a  list such as [2,2,0,2] and I then need to return a new list of the indexes for the elements in the list that are not 0 so for the list of [2,2,0,2] I would need to return [0,1,3]. Or for [1,0,1,1]  I would need to return [0,2,3].

```
def test(B):
    for k in list(B):
        if k > 0:
            result = []
            for i in range(len(B)):
                result.append(i)
        return result
```

```
test([2,2,0,2])
->[0,1,2,3]
```

My issue is that all of the indexes get returned and I have tried to fix this but have had no luck. If anyone could help that'd me great, thanks.

Comment: why are you nesting another for-loop? That is definitely not necessary. In any case, that inner loop simply copies the list to `result`, so `result` will always be the original list, (unless all the numbers are less than or equal to 0, in which case it would produce a `NameError`). You'd make your life easier if you use `enumerate`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to achieve this neatly:

```
def legal(B):
    return [i for i, x in enumerate(B) if x]
    # or if you want to cover more than numbers
    # return [i for i, x in enumerate(B) if x != 0]

>>> legal([2,2,0,2])
[0, 1, 3]
>>> legal([1,0,1,1])
[0, 2, 3]
```

Comment: schwobaseggl: I believe you've got the comments following the `return` backwards — the way it's written covers more than just just numbers because of the way `truthiness` is determined in Python.

Comment: @martineau Depends on perspective, I guess. If  `B` only contains numbers, the behaviour will be the desired one.  If there can be other stuff and all you want to exclude are `0`s, then the alternative would apply. That's what I meant by "cover".

Comment: The sense I meant was simply that using `if x` already covers more than just numbers, whereas the alternative of `if x != 0` would apply only numeric values.

Answer (score 1):

this should do the work :

```py
def indices(some_list):
    indices_list = []
    for i in range(0, len(some_list)):
        if some_list[i] != 0:
            indices_list.append(i)
    return indices_list
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use list comprehension like below

```py
ls = [2,2,0,2]

ind = [i for i, val in enumerate(ls) if val!=0]

print(ind)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
def legal(B):
    result = []
    for i, k in enumerate(list(B)):
        if k > 0:
            result.append(i)
        return result
```

Why are you doing `list(B)`? If B is not a list then this should work. If it is you should remove the `list` function.